# Use Puppet to test connection of Oracle database

Tags: oracle, configuration, puppet

My application needs Oracle database as a pre-requisite. So before install my app, I prepare a property file like below:

```
DB_CONNECTION_STRING=oracle_server:1526:SID
USER_NAME=xxxx
USER_PSWD=xxxx
```

I want to configure Puppet to check the availablity of Oracle database before deployment.
Any one know how to do it with Puppet?

Any Puppet expert here to help please? 
To rephase, this is how to use Puppet to read the property file and use the properties to try to connect a remote Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might help:

https://github.com/stschulte/puppet-oracle